# display option value in div on change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

how to display selected value of option in an empty div with jquery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let from_select = $('#from_select');
  let from_text = $('#from');

  //example#1
  from_select.on('change', function() {
    from_text.append($("option:selected").val());
  })

  //example#2
  from_select.on('change', function() {
    from_text.append($("#test option:selected").val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="from_select">
  <option id="test" value="gel" selected data-buy="1" data-sell="1">GEL</option>
  <option id="test" value="usd" data-buy="" data-sell="">USD</option>
  <option id="test" value="eur" data-buy="" data-sell="">EUR</option>
  <option id="test" value="rub" data-buy="" data-sell="">RUB</option>
</select>

<div id="from"></div>
```

in **example#1** it works, but then i cant remove last value which was passed in `#from` div.
but in **example#2** it doesn't work, i dont know why but it's not gettind id `#test`.

Comment: The second example doesn't work because your selector is wrong. The `select` has the `id` of `from_select`, your jQuery is using `#tornike`. Voting to close as a typo. Also note that the first example should be using `$(this).val()`.

Comment: I fixed the second example, but it's not working either.

Comment: Because you changed it to `#test` instead of `#from_select`...

Answer (score 1):

**Example#1**

1. You could read the selected value from `$(this).val()`.
2. you should use `.html` instead of `.append`.it will replace the previously added value from the `form`

**Example#2**

And second one not working because id of `#tornike` element not there in your markup. And this not necessary. because already you are in `onchange` event so you will get the value from the event . So `id` target was unnecessary

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let from_select = $('#from_select');
  let from_text = $('#from');

  //example#1
  from_select.on('change', function() {
    from_text.html($(this).val());
  })

   //not necessary 
  //example#2
 // from_select.on('change', function() {
   // from_text.append($("#tornike option:selected").val());
  //})

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="from_select">
  <option id="test" value="gel" selected data-buy="1" data-sell="1">GEL</option>
  <option id="test" value="usd" data-buy="" data-sell="">USD</option>
  <option id="test" value="eur" data-buy="" data-sell="">EUR</option>
  <option id="test" value="rub" data-buy="" data-sell="">RUB</option>
</select>



<div id="from">

</div>
```

Comment: no, i changed it on `#test` but it's not workin either.

Comment: @Tornike_14 second not necessary. because already you are in onchange event so you will get the value from the event . So `id` target was unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the below option

```
 $(this).val() 
 from_select.val()
```